# error: "net.ipv6" is an unknown key

Tags: linux, linux-networking, centos6, ipv6, sysctl

On one of my CentOS 6 machines I get

```
$ sudo sysctl net.ipv6
error: "net.ipv6" is an unknown key
```

Why do I see this and how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have ipv6 configured? `grep -i ipv6 /boot/config-*` should tell you.

Comment: @NickD What am I looking for in the output ?

Comment: `CONFIG_IPV6=y` probably - and you should select the config file for the kernel you are running.

Comment: Are you running an official CentOS kernel, did you compile your own?  Is this a VPS or something running a non-standard kernel?